# Infinity loop in sending data to the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I want to update the data in a database (only one field in one record of JSON), but I get an infinity loop in sending data. I am not sure, where is the problem, so I want to ask the StackOverflow community for help.

So, I have one record in MongoDB:

```
_id: ... some ID ...
active:true
nameOfEvent: .. same name ..
creatorId: ...some ID ...
createdAt: 2021-01-28T16:49:02.374+00:00
updatedAt: 2021-02-08T12:07:42.364+00:00
__v: 0
codeEvent: ... some code ...
participants: [Array]
```

And to the array **participants**, I want to insert one record (not infinity :-) )

frontend:

```
        addResultOfUserToParticipants(eventValues._id, participant).then(data => {
            if(!data.error){
                setSendStatus({...sendStatus, success: true, error: false});
                
            }
            else{
                setSendStatus({...sendStatus, success: false, error: data.error});
            }
        })
```

frontend fetching:

```
export const addResultOfUserToParticipants = (eventId, resultOfQuiz) => {
    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/event/addParticipant/${eventId}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(resultOfQuiz)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

backand route:

```
//add participant of event with result from quiz
router.post("/event/addParticipant/:eventId", addResultOfQuizToEventHistory);
```

backend:

```
const addResultOfQuizToEventHistory = (req, res) => {
    Event.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.event._id}, {$push: {'participants': req.body}}, {useFindAndModify: false}, (err) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                err: 'Error while inserting to participants'
            });
        }
        else{
            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: 'OK'
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Do you have any idea to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: you need to show us how do you trigger the API call

Comment: Thanks for idea, I edit main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you calling the `addResultOfUserToParticipants` function?

Comment: Thanks for pointing up my issue! This was my issue. In frontend I had no correct close of executing function addResultOfUserToParticipants. I edited if,else statement and now it is working! Thanks.